# Object reference not set to an instance of an object for third part dll IsCrypto

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am using some third party dlls in my vb.net winform project. I have added this dll's as reference in my project as Interop.IsCrypto.dll. Also the same  dll's are present in the bin folder. It was working fine in windows 2008 server but giving object reference error in windows 2012 R2 server. There must be some issue with server which I am not able to identify. Below is the code. Please advice.

```
Dim l_objCrypto As ISCrypto.System
Dim l_objErrorPackager As ISErrorPkgr3.System
'Code running upto this statement only
WriteLog("ISCrypto.System", False) 'This is printed in log
'At below statement it gives runtime error - object reference not...
l_objCrypto = New ISCrypto.System
WriteLog("ISErrorPkgr3.System", False) ' This is not printed in log
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is Interop.*.dll, then it is native code which is accessible in .NET via COM interface (not COM port!). This COM needs to be registered either by that library's installer, or by using regsvr32 utility in command prompt.

Comment: when I am trying to register it via regsvr32 command then it is giving me the error: Register interop.IsCrypto.dll DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Comment: Of course. You must register original DLL, not Interop DLL generated by Visual Studio.